# Unable to install because of missing ninja

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, catkin-make-isolated, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the diagnostics module from source into my existing Kinetic source installation.

To do this, I'm running:

```
cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws;
rosinstall_generator diagnostics --rosdistro kinetic --deps | wstool merge -t src -
wstool update -t src -j2 --delete-changed-uris
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y -r --os=debian:jessie
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic -j1
```

It's failing when trying to install the dependency Opencv3, with the error:

```
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3/install
==> ninja -j1 in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3/install'
/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh: 16: exec: ninja: not found
<== Failed to process package 'opencv3': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh', 'ninja', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 127

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3 && /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh ninja -j1

Command failed, exiting.
```

What "ninja" program is it referring to, and why wasn't this auto-installed by rosdep? There appears to be both an apt package and pip package called "ninja", which do very different things, so it's unclear which one it's expecting.

Edit: I'm assuming it's referring to the [ninja build](https://ninja-build.org/) system? I tried installing the `ninja-build` package, and re-running the build process, but that reports a different but similar ninja error:

```
==> Processing plain cmake package: 'opencv3'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3/install'
==> ninja -j1 in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3/install'
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory
<== Failed to process package 'opencv3': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh', 'ninja', '-j1']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/opencv3 && /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh ninja -j1
```

How do I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244214/unable-to-install-because-of-missing-ninja/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-09-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-22**:
Somehow CMake is generating build files for `ninja` (the build tool, not the python library), which is definitely not standard.

As `opencv3` is a "plain cmake" package, it might be doing some strange things. Perhaps OpenCV3's build files are hard-coding a generator?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-22**:
CMake should also output the generator it is using for your build scripts. Can you find that anywhere in the output?

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-09-22**:
@gvdhoorn, What is the generator called? What am I looking for?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-22**:
The generator is called `ninja`. See [cmake-generators(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) and [What is a CMake generator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941536/what-is-a-cmake-generator) for some discussion on generators.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-22**:
But more interesting would be to understand why CMake chose the *ninja* generator in the first place: did this ever happen before? Can you successfully use `rosinstall_generator` to build other pkgs?

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-09-22**:
I still don't understand. Like I said in my question, it's outputting `ninja`, so I'm not sure why you're telling me to look for it. The problem is the ninja build script isn't being generated, so ninja is throwing an error. And yes, the first command I ran was `rosinstall_generator`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-22**:
Nowhere in ROS is the CMake *generator* being configured. Afaik, all catkin driven CMake activity uses the *GNU Makefile* generator. Something in your setup is forcing CMake to use the *ninja* generator. That is something to figure out. Who or what is making CMake use the ninja generator.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-22**:
As to the output I'm asking for: CMake uses its generators at *configuration* time, not *build* time. I'm asking whether you see any output during initial configuration that states that CMake is using its ninja generator. Lines regarding that should appear *before* the lines you've copy/pasted.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-22**:
I'm also assuming here that you haven't somehow configured CMake to always use ninja.

If OpenCV3 forces ninja to be used, then obviously that is the culprit.

As to the error message you see after installing ninja-build: I'm guessing Catkin doesn't know about ninja, and doesn't invoke it correctly.

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2016-09-23**:
Have you tried with any other package ? (unrelated to OpenCV)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-23**:
@Vincent Rabaud: does opencv3 force use of the *ninja* generator? (I haven't checked, so this may be a strange question to ask).

**Comment by [Qamar](https://answers.ros.org/users/28055/qamar/) on 2016-09-23**:
I'm receiving same errors when compiling `octomap` on Raspberry pi.

```
==> Processing plain cmake package: 'octomap'
[..]
==> ninja -j4 in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/octomap/install'
/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh: 16: exec: ninja: not found
```

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-09-23**:
@Vincent, It's a source installation, so I've installed all packages from source, and this is the only one that's given me this error.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-09-23**:
@Vincent, How would I check if opencv3 forces ninja? [It appears to be mentioned in their CMakeLists](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), but I'm not completely familiar with CMake's format, so I can't say if it's being forced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In src/catkin/python/catkin/builder.py line 532, make the following change:

```
@@ -527,11 +527,11 @@
         run_command_colorized(
             make_check_cmake_cmd, build_dir, quiet
         )
 
     # Run make
-    if not use_ninja:
+    if use_ninja:
         make_executable = 'ninja'
     elif use_nmake:
         make_executable = 'nmake'
     else:
         make_executable = 'make'
```

---

Originally posted by [jb](https://answers.ros.org/users/28068/jb/) with karma: 26 on 2016-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-25**:
@Cerin: this could indeed be the cause of Catkin using the ninja generator. What I haven't figured out yet is why it only tries to do that with OpenCV3, but it's a bug in any case.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-09-25**:
The bug only affected plain CMake packages. This is being addressed by https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/827

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2016-09-25**:
Thx @dirk-thomas !

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-09-25**:
Great find. Thank you.